# Package an Android app with Trigger.io Forge

Tags: android, apk, keystore, trigger.io

I'm able to *serve* and *run* my app on Android (emulators, real device over ADB), but when I try to package the APk and install it on a device, I get an error. It seems like the *package* works just fine (an APK comes out with no error), but when I try to install my device says:

> An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.

My sample app name is "boop" and I just made the keys/alias from scratch, so I'm not sure I really believe there is a conflict.

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Figured it out.

I'd tested the application over ADB on this device. Seems like that actually **installs** the APK (which might be common knowledge, but I pictured some kinda temporary thing).

To get my actual signed APK to install, I just needed to uninstall the current version of "boop" on my device.